# References to the same document are all different when saving to Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have the following function on my Express+Node backend to save new "Results"

```
var saveResult = function(username, result, callback){

    var resultItem = new models.Round_Results({
        round: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(result.round),
        selection: 10,
        time: 15
    });
    models.User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user){
        user.results.push(resultItem);
        user.save(function(err, result){
            if (err)
                console.log("ERROR! " + err);
            else
                callback(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Everything is OK with the Schemas etc.

The problem is, that I am expecting if I push the same "Result" from the frontend 10 times, I'll see all the same data in each object in the array.

But that's not the case. I've `POST`ed the following data 3 times and here are my results:

```
{round: 555ec731385b4d604356d8e5, selection: 1, time: 20}
```

Results from server:

```
{
    "result": {
        "_id": "5570fe093beeefcc80f44439",
        "username": "moe",
        "password": "moe",
        "__v": 10,
        "firstname": "Da Real Moe",
        "results": [
            {
                "_id": "557225ba7588942040301b8c",
                "time": 15,
                "selection": 10,
                "round": "557225ba7588942040301b8b"
            },
            {
                "_id": "557225bd7588942040301b8e",
                "time": 15,
                "selection": 10,
                "round": "557225bd7588942040301b8d"
            },
            {
                "_id": "557225bf7588942040301b90",
                "time": 15,
                "selection": 10,
                "round": "557225bf7588942040301b8f"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How could the `round` be different? I gave it the same round each time!

Comment: What is in your Schema?